# how to add attr_accessible to database table in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, schema

I'm getting this error while doing rake:seed. can't mass-assign protected attributes

I know that they are other posts about this error and the solution is to add attr_accessible to the model, but I dont know how to add it in `ActiveRecord::Schema.define`

Actually I'm learning rails from the book pragmatic book I got this code from that book,

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120814110309) do

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "descripton"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",      :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               :null => false
  end

end
```

I got to add attr_accessible to description, so how do I do that

UPDATE:

my products.rb has attr_accessible, already, but its not working!?

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
    attr_accessible :descripton, :image_url, :price, :title
end
```

UPDATE:

*I figured it out, it was a typo problem, thanx anyway, its working  but I didntget the actual solution that is adding attr_accessable in scema rather adding it in model. If thats a bad idea, why is it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attr_accessible doens't go on schema.rb. It goes on your model. Based on the code you posted above you probably want:

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title, :description # Add as needed
end
```

Comment: ya that will work, thanks, I know that it will work, but I was wondering if I can add it from schema, thanks anyway

Comment: It's in your product and you still get the mass-assignment errors? If so, post your product.rb code and I will take a look.